# How to join using complex expression using Linq2Sql C# Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax

I need to implement such query: In C# Linq2Sql Statements this can be written so:

```
var query = from f1 in Foo
            from f2 in Foo
            where f1.Id < f2.Id && f1.Value == f2.Value
            select f1;
```

But I wonder how to do this using C# Expressions. I mean something like this:

```
var query = Foo.Join(...).Select(...);
```

I see that Join method gives opportunity only to use equal join `f1.Id == f2.Id`. But how to write in C# expressions more complex query expressions, where is, for example, such expression as `f1.Id < f2.Id`?

Comment: What are c1 and c2? And your join has no on clause...

Comment: Sorry, it should be f1.Value == f2.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739578/how-to-join-using-complex-expression-using-linq2sql-c-expressions/4739862#4739862) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739578/how-to-join-using-complex-expression-using-linq2sql-c-expressions/4739688#4739688) will produce the same result, it doesn't translate to the same semantically to the original query syntax.

If you want something semantically closer to the original query syntax, you would use the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension method, as that is what query syntax translates to when you have more than one `from` clause:

```
var query = Foo.
    // from f1 in Foo
    // from f2 in Foo 
    //
    // Need the anonymous type to carry over the two items
    // in the sequences, the compiler will do the same
    // in your original query, although the names
    // will be much more mangled.
    SelectMany(f => Foo, (f1, f2) => new { f1, f2 }).

    // f1.Id < f2.Id && f1.Value == f2.Value 
    Where(f => f.f1.Id < f.f2.Id && f.f1.Value == f.f2.Value).

    // select f1;
    Select(f => f.f1);
```

Also, it should be noted that while you can use the `Join` method, you can **only** use it in situations where you want inner join semantics based on equality.  Anything else and you have to use `SelectMany` with a call to `Where`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct conversion since your original query isn't using a join...but I think this might get you close:

```
var query = Foo.Join(Foo, 
                     f1 => f1.Value, 
                     f2 => f2.Value, 
                     (f1, f2) => new { f1, f2 })
               .Where(g => g.f1.Id < g.f2.Id)
               .Select(g => g.f1);
```

Comment: @Justin Niessner: There is a direct conversion, `SelectMany` and anonymous types.

Comment: @casperOne - The OP specifically asked how to accomplish his goal using a Join...not other operators.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: There is not a specific request for using `Join`, but rather, something "like" a join; the concentration IMO is on "C# Expressions" (which I assume he means is the non-query-syntax version).

Comment: @casperOne - Guess it's all in how you interpret the question. All the more reason to be as clear as possible when you post to StackOverflow!

Comment: @BothOfYou - Based on the query in the OP, don't you think it's *very likely* that the original structure was a bit misguided?  (And should just be rewritten rather than just translated into method syntax?)  The original structure suggests that the asker simply may not be very familiar with joins.  And as you both know (20k+ rep) a huge portion of SO questions are really just asking the wrong question, no?

Comment: @shaunmartin: While it's true that `Join` could be used here to give a better semantic meaning overall to the OP's query, I think it would be a worse idea to send the op down the direction of thinking that `Join` could be used for *all* queries like this (which it can't, which is why I specified only "inner join semantics based on equality").

Answer (score 0):

If you rearrange your query, you might be able to stick with the **expression syntax which is simple and readable**.  How about joining on the `.Value` property and filtering on `f1.Id < f2.Id`?  That should provide the results you're looking for.

```
var query = from f1 in Foo
            join f2 in Foo on f1.Value equals f2.Value
            where f1.Id < f2.Id
            select f1;
```